# isoformat function of datetime module in python returns incorrect offset

Tags: python, python-datetime, pytz

So I have -

```
timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
one_time_stamp = '2017-06-01 05:30:00'

zoned_time_stamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(one_time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#This outputs 2017-06-01 05:30:00 which is fine.
print(zoned_time_stamp)

#notice timezone added
non_iso_zoned_ts = zoned_time_stamp.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=timezone)
# This outputs 2017-06-01 05:30:00 which is fine.
print(zoned_time_stamp)

iso_date = non_iso_zoned_ts.isoformat()
#This outputs 2017-06-01T05:30:00+05:53 which is incorrect. Ideally it should be 2017-06-01T05:30:00+05:30
print(iso_date)
```

Now I wonder why isoformat is adding an offset of 05:53 where as timezone Asia/Kolkata is +05:30. ref - https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/timezone/asia--kolkata

Comment: Consider using [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) or [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) (Python 3.9). pytz [will be deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237932/timezone-offsets-not-printing-to-a-rounded-hour (there's *many* more of those on SO...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost always wrong to just tack on a pytz instance for the tzinfo when creating a datetime. The correct way to convert a naive datetime into a timezone aware instance using pytz is with the zone's localize method:

```
zone.localize(dt)
```

Output for your case:

```
>>> print(timezone.localize(zoned_time_stamp))
2017-06-01 05:30:00+05:30
```

It's quite [clearly documented](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/release_2024.1/src/README.rst#example--usage) that passing a pytz instance in tzinfo is not a supported way of creating a localized datetime. However, that's also such a commonly seen mistake in Python code - guess many users don't read the docs!

To understand why the incorrect approach showed what it did (weird `+05:53` offset), refer to [*pytz: The Fastest Footgun in the West*](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) by Paul Ganssle.