# Timezone offsets not printing to a rounded hour

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

When I run the following code;

```
tz_Pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
tz_Tasmania = pytz.timezone('Australia/Tasmania')

time1 = datetime(2020, 10, 7, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz_Pacific)
time2 = datetime(2020, 10, 7, 14, 20, 21, tzinfo=tz_Tasmania)

print(time1)
print(time2)
```

I get the following output;

```
2020-10-07 18:00:00-07:53

2020-10-07 14:20:21+09:49
```

Why would the tz offsets be -07:53 and +09:49 respectively?

Comment: I note that these are the offsets before the first transition in the IANA database (1883 for US/Pacific and 1895 for Australia/Tasmania). I don't know anything about pytz, but it seems to be ignoring the dates you've provided...

Comment: @JonSkeet: your suspicion is correct I think. And this is a common issue with `pytz`; there are *lots* of questions on SO where people stumbled across this "caveat" of the pytz API. [The docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) are clear about how to building a localized time - but it's hard to spot the warning sign that tells you what happens if you *dont't* use one of the two valid methods.

Answer (score 1):

Why you get these "weired" offsets with `pytz`? Those are the first entries from the database for the respective time zones. With `pytz`, if you don't localize, these won't be adjusted to the time of your datetime object. Here's a [nice blog post](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) by Paul Ganssle giving more insights.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz_Pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
tz_Tasmania = pytz.timezone('Australia/Tasmania')

# note the LMT for local mean time:
print(repr(tz_Pacific))
print(repr(tz_Tasmania))
# <DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' LMT-1 day, 16:07:00 STD> 
# <DstTzInfo 'Australia/Tasmania' LMT+9:49:00 STD>

# correctly localized you get
time1 = tz_Pacific.localize(datetime(2020, 10, 7, 18, 0, 0))
time2 = tz_Tasmania.localize(datetime(2020, 10, 7, 14, 20, 21))
print(time1)
print(time2)
# 2020-10-07 18:00:00-07:00
# 2020-10-07 14:20:21+11:00
```

***Further remarks:***

- With Python 3.9+, you have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) as part of the standard library to do this.
- Example: [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418).
- Note that there is a [deprecation shim for pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).